# How can I update an attribute in a DynamoDB table regardless of the key or condition?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table say `data`. This table has 400k items. Each item has 4 fields -

- id (string) this is my partition key
- status (Y/N)
- date_added
- source

Right now all items have a `status` = "Y". How can I update all items and set the status to "N" for all 400k items irrespective of the key or any condition?

In MySQL, an equivalent statement would be -

```
UPDATE data SET status = 'N';
```

I am looking to do it either through the command line or preferable in python using boto3

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy or cheap way to do what you want to do. What you'll basically need to do is to **read** and **write** the entire database:

**write**:

1. If you know the key of a single item, you can do a `UpdateItem` request with an `UpdateExpression` of `"set status = :N"`. This will only modify the "status" attribute (leaving the rest unchanged), but the cost you will incur (or provisioned throughput you will use) will be the cost of writing the entire item. So the sum of all these operations will be the cost of re-writing the entire database.
2. You should add to the above `UpdateItem` a `ConditionExpression` that will only update the item if the item actually still exists (you can use a `attribute_exists()` condition on its key attribute to verify that an item exists). This will allow your workload to delete items while doing these changes.
3. Before starting this change process, change your client code to write *new* items with status = N. The change process may miss these new items, but it's fine if they are already created with status = N.
4. You can't use `BatchWriteItems` (`batch_writer()` in boto3) to modify a group of items together, because this batch operation can only replace items - not modify an attribute of existing items. In any case, a `BatchWriteItems` would not have reduced the costs (batches cost the same as the requests they contain).

**read**:

1. To get a list of all extant keys in the database, to do the above reads, you need to use a `Scan` operation, with `Projection` set to `KEYS_ONLY` to get only the keys (you don't need the data). The cost to you will be the same as read the *entire* item, unfortunately, not just reading the keys. So the sum of the cost of all these Scan operations will be reading the entire database.

If you are using **provisioned capacity** for this table, you may be able to use whatever excess capacity you have that is not used by client requests to do this change slowly, in the background, basically for "free".

Whether or not this makes sense in your case really depends on how much excess capacity (both read and write!) you have provisioned. If you do this, you'll need to watch out not to use too much capacity for this background operation and hurt your real users - you'll need to have some sort of controller that notices capacity-exceeded errors and reduce the amount of capacity used by the background process.

If you actually have a lot of excess provisioned capacity that you've already paid for, you can do this background operation as quickly as you want! The read part, a `Scan`, can be done in parallel as quickly as you want (using the "parallel scan" feature), and the write part for different keys can also, obviously, be done in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses `batch_write_item` DynamoDB API to update items in batches of size 25, which is the maximum number of items that `batch_write_item` can take in a single API call. You might need to tweak this number if your items are large.

Warning: This is just a proof of concept example. You should use at your own risk.

```python
import boto3

def update_status(item):
    item['status'] = {
        'S': 'N'
    }
    return item

client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='<ddb-region>')
paginator = client.get_paginator('scan')
operation_parameters = {
  'TableName': '<ddb-table-name>',
  'PaginationConfig': {
    'PageSize': 25
  }
}
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)
for page in page_iterator:
    response = client.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
        '<ddb-table-name>': [
            {
                'PutRequest': {
                    'Item': update_status(item)
                }
            }
            for item in page['Items']
        ]
    })
    print(response)
```

Comment: Note that this example code reads the entire existing items, modifies them in the client, and writes back the *entire* item. This is risky, and wrong, if there are concurrent writes to the same database - your loop may overwrite those other changes. This is why in my answer above I suggested to update **just** the 'status' attribute - not rewrite the entire item (I also mentioned BatchWriteItem, but that was wrong, I'll fix it now).

Comment: Well, this is just a PoC. You can certainly add some conditions to prevent concurrent write. @NadavHar'El

Comment: But you don't need to prevent concurrent write if you can just have your write modify the 'status' attribute, and nothing else. There is no real need to read all the attributes and write all of them back. I noted in my own answer how you do need to add a condition to deal with a concurrent delete (in case someone is deleting an item in parallel with you "fixing" its "status").

Comment: Update item one at a time is pretty slow. @NadavHar'El This is just another idea to speed things up.

Comment: As I noted in my answer, you can parallelize this updates as much as you want. You can send 100 UpdateItem request in parallel. Unfortunately DynamoDB doesn't support HTTP 2 so you need to do these 100 request over 100 HTTP connections, but it's still practical. I agree with you that if you have relatively small items and no concurrent updates, your approach will be good too.